# Trying to deliberately corrupt images using bufferedImages

Tags: java, image, corruption

I am trying to deliberately corrupt an input image.

```
        BufferedImage bImage = ImageIO.read(new File("input.jpg"));
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(bImage, "jpg", bos);
        byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();

        for (int x = 0; x < bImage.getHeight(); x++) {
                int yesNo = (int) Math.round(Math.random());
                int r = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
                int g = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
                int b = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
                Color myColor = new Color(r, g, b);

                if (yesNo == 1) {
                    data[x] = (byte) myColor.getRGB();
                }
        }

        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
        BufferedImage bImage2 = ImageIO.read(bis);
        ImageIO.write(bImage2, "jpg", new File("output.jpg"));
```

When I convert my image into a byte array and change the values it sometimes outputs grey pixels instead of randomized colored ones. Here is my input and output (my friend suggested the image not me).

[input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRrVv.jpg) and [output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8gHz.jpg)

I did some research as well and I found that if I open the file in a hex editor and change values at random it gives me my desired result. Maybe I could somehow replicate that in java? ([desired image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIy7Q.jpg). Wouldn't mind if it was more messed up.)

Comment: It sounds like instead of trying to corrupt the image, you actually want to corrupt the binary file?

Comment: @phflack as long as the output jpg or png file is messed up it doesn't matter to me.

Comment: It depends on what kind of changes you're expecting, if you're trying to change random pixels to be new values, I suspect you want to use BufferedImage to make the edits.  Your current code is probably reading the raw file and making edits to metadata

Comment: Isn't that what changing hex values does?

Comment: Normally image files are compressed and the beginning tends to be data about the rest of the file.  If you mess with this, unexpected things may happen.  If this is what you're aiming for, instead of messing with `(byte)Color.getRGB()`, maybe you should just use `Random.nextByte()`?  Currently you're making a 24 bit number, and then taking the last 8 bits _(aka the green value)_

Comment: If you're trying to modify the image's pixel values, you might want to look into [`BufferedImage.setRGB(int x, int y, int rgb)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#setRGB(int,%20int,%20int))

Comment: I used the `BufferedImage.setRGB()` and its not necessarily the result I was looking for. I think it would be better to change byte values from the byte array. Is it possible to differentiate meta data from the image data itself?

Comment: I've only modified/written pngs before, but it looks like the [specification is on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Syntax_and_structure)

Comment: Okay that all makes sense. However, when I put my buffered image to my byte array, how do I search the array for those hex values? I opened the same image in a hex editor and found the image data and was able to change it and get what I wanted. How do I code that?

Comment: I would recommend first printing out the values in the array, to check if match the hex editor and if the array is indeed the raw image data, otherwise we have a whole different issue

Comment: I made it print to a txt file and I found that it had the same formatting wikipedia said it would have. I found the 0xFF, 0xDA which is the start of the image. So if I wrote code to corrupt after there it would work. Only problem is that a few addresses after that there is "entropy-coded data". I don't think I can overwrite that.

Comment: Well, see what happens if you do overwrite it?  You might end up with some really funky looking stuff

Comment: You cannot overwrite it, however, I think I have figured out a constant. If you search for the two consecutive memory addresses 0xFF and 0xDA there is only one. Then you skip 9 addresses for the data entropy you are there. This represents the start of the actual data of the image. So now I need to write code to search for this address and write after that. Thank you so much and if you are willing to help me set this up with a website feel free to contact me on discord Unprotested#1061.

Answer (score -1):

you should use "png" foramt instead

Comment: Buffered image uses jpg not pngs.

Comment: @unprotested BufferedImage will write in whichever format you tell it to, I use it to write pngs

Comment: @unprotested you are wrong,  i have used it  without any problem

Comment: @phflack I changed the JPGs to PNGs and it gave me this error: IOException: javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!

Comment: @unprotested Oh, only just realized you changed the read as well as the write.  If you try to read a .jpg as a .png, it's going to freak out because they're different formats.  You should be able to write the `BufferedImage` as .png without issue, while still reading the .jpg as a .jpg

Comment: @ahmed intentional image corruption would produce very different results with png, jpg artifacts are very popular for such projects and can be very artistic. thankyou for your well intentioned suggestion though